# if it's possible to configure hibernate to ignore missing resources in hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Tags: java, configuration, hibernate-mapping

I have some test tables mappings in my hibernate.cfg.xml file, for example:

```
<mapping resource="com/db/dummyentity.hbm.xml"/>
```

If this resource isn't exist in class path then my schema creation process will fail,
there is any way to configure hibernate to ignore missing resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it is not possible**. If you provide a resource mapping in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file it have to be present in that particular location, otherwise it will fail.
Although config xml is not a **mandatory** file in hibernate.If you call `Configuration#configure()` method,to set your required properties(for example), then only hibernate will look for `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.